# Inline element will not rest even with other inline images

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

When I make a jsfiddle to practice what I would like to do on the website it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/texascapresident/27g6f8dw/

HTML

```
<div class="link-image-container">
    <a href="https://twitter.com"><img class="employee-contact-images" src="http://www.texasca.com/graphics/icons/twitter-link.png" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/zacharygcook" target="_blank" ><img class="employee-contact-images" src="http://www.texasca.com/graphics/icons/linkedin-link.png" /></a>
    <form class="form-containing-email" action="contact-team-member.php" method="POST">
        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="teamMemberName" VALUE="Zach">
        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="teamMemberTitle" VALUE="CTO" >
        <input type="image" class="special-email-image" src="http://www.texasca.com/graphics/icons/email-link.png" >
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-containing-email {
    display: inline;
}
```

However, in practice on the website, one of the images (the one in the form) behaves strangely.

[image: On the site it messes up]

As you can see, the last image is kind of "popped up". I'm not sure what is going wrong.

The HTML & CSS on the website is slightly more complicated, feel free to check it out for yourself.

HTML of site: http://texasca.com/team.html

CSS of site: http://texasca.com/includes/team.css

Please help me out if you can! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the form (`<form class="form-containing-email" action="contact-team-member.php" method="POST">`) in that section `vertical-align:top`.